# Do you like hats?

Tags: discussion

Last year around Christmas time [arQAde](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) had an awesome promotion in which they awarded hats for gravatars for completing basic tasks around the site. If you don't remember it, here is a [link](http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) the promo from last year (and [another!](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/)).

[image: hats]

This year, SE is planning to run it for *everyone* because we all love hats, right? right?

But to get this awesome hat promotion we have to **opt in**. That means acting on this meta post, whether that's voting it up, answering in the affirmative, positive comments and/or just directing positive energy this direction.

I think this is a good chance at a bit of harmless fun, that could potentially help keep site traffic up through the northern hemisphere winter (when traffic usually dies down a bit for us).

HOWEVER: this promotion is **optional** for sites, and/or individual users. If the users of this site *do not* want this in general feel free to voice that opinion. We can opt out of the promotion. Individual users will be able to opt out as well (they will be provided with an "I hate Hats" link to opt out).

Again, please let us know what you think as this is your site not ours.

(Majority of content blatantly stolen from [freiheit](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/users/76/freiheit)'s copy of [waxeagle](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/49/wax-eagle)'s [post on meta.christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/do-you-like-hats).)

Comment: Sounds like something Russell would be into.  What sort of things do you do to earn hats?  What hats do you propose?  I can think of a duncecap for the opposite, but what sort of hat do you use to show someone was particularly clever?

Comment: Merlin's cap, a wizard's cap with stars and other symbols perhaps.

Comment: @OlinLathrop You get hats for being friendly to new users :)

Comment: W5V0: That's no fun then. @Anindo: I like the Merlin's cap though. Maybe a Sherlock Holmes cap for figuring out what the OP did wrong despite his description. I still want to award a duncecap to those that didn't read the datasheet and did stupid stuff as a result. Moderators might get a viking helmet with horns. I think Kortuk would look good in one :-)

Comment: @OlinLathrop Are Deerstalkers politically correct, then? ;-) But yeah, "the sleuthing reward" cap is a cool idea. How about a bright yellow safety helmet for when an answer is leading an OP straight up the path to magic smoke time?

Comment: @OlinLathrop Viking helmets are pretty cool. But I'm in favor of a slightly more modern and yet still retro look in my moderators: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131543/hats-are-too-awesome-for-stack-exchange-not-to-have/131902#131902

Comment: Now that this is definitely coming, people may want to update their avatars so as to make more sense when wearing a hat.  Too often we see avatars here that have way too much detail for the 32x32 pixels shown with questions and answers.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I have a perfect avatar, but these hats are just way too large for me. (yes: I'm way in over my head)

Comment: I still like hats BTW ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hats have it! Starting December 19th through January 4th, we will have hats. Stay tuned for more details (or hats).

Comment: Should I stay tuned again?

Answer (score 7):

<s>Will there be a"**you're way in over your head**"-cap</s>

Will there be a "**you're way in over your hat**"?

For eg. questions about "not having any prior experience in electronics, but about to design a 4GHz x86_64 motherboard on a breadboard"?

Or "transformerless mains power supplies for kids toys"?

I guess it should be an oversized hat ;o) What are your opinions?

Comment: How about a ton of rope with a noose on the end?

Answer (score 3):

Toronto gets cold in wintertime. A hat is appropriate (and warming), even if only virtual. +1.

Comment: hey @Madmanguruman is there a way to send you a message via pm? (it's not about hats)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of (in the SE context.)

Answer (score 3):

"Convicted" (6 flags) spammers should be forced (so non-optional) to wear donkey ears on their avatars. And when they try to click the "I don't like hats", a complimentary donkey tail should appear.

Can we have that implemented before January 4th or at least for next year's mad hattery?

Comment: Spammer accounts go the way of the bit bucket.

Answer (score 2):

Mumbai's pretty hot and sweaty even in winter. A swimmer's cap would look a bit odd though, I suspect.

Comment: A strawhat is what you need :)

Comment: Agreed! That'd be the last straw.

Answer (score 1):

And some hats should be able to be used at the same time.  Like the moustache and a jaunty hat, for example.

Comment: and headphones: Jammin'out

Answer (score 0):

Hats are cute, I guess, but to me they seem to be largely functionally redundant with badges.

My big complaint is that the additional client-side scripting used to implement them is *really* slowing down my browser. I had to turn them off.

Comment: I have had no noticeable difference on the site, hmm. I do see it take a bit longer to load users pictures though.